# How can I fix this drywall?

Tags: drywall

The previous owner of my house attempted to finish the basement, which he didn't end up following through. Which is a good thing, because a lot of stuff was done wrong. Some of which are these drywall installation on a wide angle corner.

[image]

[image]

So as you can see, the corners of the top and bottom sheets don't line up and there's a quite a large gap between the top and bottom sheets where my finger is. The bottom sheet is proud, about 1/4" and tapers off away from the finger. The bottom sheets are flipped upside down too, but that's an easy fix, IMO.

How do I go about fixing these issues? Should I take off the triangular piece, cut back to line up the corner and redo? Of course I don't know what the framing looks like behind.

Or can I build up with hot mud on the triangular side? Is that even practical? If I build up with mud, what do I do with the corner?

Comment: Probably redoing the work would be easier than having to do patch jobs to try to make it look right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on where in the house this is, and your aesthetic requirements for that area, you have a few options.

I would redo the paneling. Every good drywall mudding job begins with good framing and good paneling. With one panel off, mount a strip of backing wood at the seam, screwing both panels into the backing. The strip does not have to be fastened to framing; it just serves to align both panels. Shim or furr out the shy panel where needed so that it is not under mechanical stress.

Alternatively, you could apply lots of mud. Begin with hot mud (setting compound) and mesh tape. Fill with hot mud to within 1/8in thick (or closer, say 1/16in). Finish with all purpose compound and a large knife (14in),  going out the full length of the knife on the panel shy side. Hot mud is hard within an hour or so, and will not shrink. The all purpose compound will shrink, and if filling more than 1/8in with it you'll likely need 24hrs drying time or so, between layers.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of following products.

Drywall mesh tape.

From 2 inch to 19 inch width.

They are stronger than regular tape and wont tear.

Apply mud generously.

[image: mesh]